# jQuery get next element in a table below the current

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a crossword puzzle and am trying to move the cursor to the next letter box automatically after typing in a letter. I can do this going across but not sure about down. I would like to go across as priority #1 and if the next box is not a letter box it searches to see if it can go down. If it can't go across or down then nothing happens.

Here is what I have for going across:

```
$('.crossword_puzzle input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
   $(this).parent().parent().next().find('input[type="text"]').focus().select();
});
```

How could I go down if across is not found?

The DOM is an html table with an input box in each TD.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT - Heres is part of the table, forgot I have a set of divs in each td too. Also there is a div holding a number at the start of each word.

```
    <table class="crossword_puzzle">
<tr>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="block_num">1</div>
         <input type="text" class="word_3_1 cp_move_across" maxlength="1" onClick="this.select();" id="x3y1" name="x3y1" value=""/>
         <div class="block_num">1</div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks"><input type="text" class="word_3_1 cp_move_across" maxlength="1" onClick="this.select();" id="x4y1" name="x4y1" value=""/></div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <input type="text" class="word_3_1 cp_move_across" maxlength="1" onClick="this.select();" id="x5y1" name="x5y1" value=""/>
         <div class="block_num">2</div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks"><input type="text" class="word_3_1 cp_move_across" maxlength="1" onClick="this.select();" id="x6y1" name="x6y1" value=""/></div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks"><input type="text" class="word_3_1 cp_move_across" maxlength="1" onClick="this.select();" id="x7y1" name="x7y1" value=""/></div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks"><input type="text" class="word_3_1 cp_move_down" maxlength="1" onClick="this.select();" id="x3y2" name="x3y2" value=""/></div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks"><input type="text" class="word_5_1 cp_move_down" maxlength="1" onClick="this.select();" id="x5y2" name="x5y2" value=""/></div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
         <div class="black_block"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="all_blocks">
```

What about this, taking @Kevin B answer below and adding a flag to switch which way the priority goes. Does anyone see an issue doing it this way? EDIT: added logical to flip direction priority based on if the next cell has text or not in the current priority order

```
var priority_direction = 'across';
    $('.crossword_puzzle input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
        if(priority_direction == 'across'){
            var next = $(this).closest('td').next().find('input[type="text"]');
            priority_direction = 'across';
            if (!next.length || next.val().length == 1) {
                var cellIndex = $(this).closest('td').index();
                next = $(this).closest('tr').next().children().eq(cellIndex).find('input[type="text"]');
                priority_direction = 'down';
            }
        } else {
            var cellIndex = $(this).closest('td').index();
            var next = $(this).closest('tr').next().children().eq(cellIndex).find('input[type="text"]');

            priority_direction = 'down';
            if (!next.length || next.val().length == 1) {
                next = $(this).closest('td').next().find('input[type="text"]');
                priority_direction = 'across';
            }
        }
        next.focus().select();
    });
```

Comment: Please post the markup.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess the HTML structure from that ?

Comment: It could be easier done with `:eq()`. If you want to go to the right simply increase the index i `:eq(i)`, if you want to go down add the number of cells/line to that number `:eq(i+n)`.

Comment: It's not that hard to guess what a table structure looks like. *"The DOM is an html table with an input box in each TD"* though it would be nice to have for testing/confirmation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the next row instead of the next td.

```
$('.crossword_puzzle input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
   var next = $(this).closest('td').next().find('input[type="text"]');
   if (!next.length) {
      var cellIndex = $(this).closest('td').index();
      next = $(this).closest('tr').next().children().eq(cellIndex).find('input[type="text"]');
   }
   next.focus().select();
});
```

Comment: This does have one fatal flaw; if you're filling in a word that is vertical and hit a crossing, it will begin to go to the right instead of continuing down. I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: If you provide an html sample, i'd be willing to take a stab at fixing that flaw.

Comment: This does work as I asked but yes it does have the oddity of moving across when going down if it hits another across word.

Comment: I modified your code in the question above, do you any problems with that?

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix this issue too. If you type in characters too fast it will skip over boxes and not input a character?

Comment: Well, after looking at your html, theres also the problem of which way do you go if two words share the same first letter.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider adding classes to each cell (eg. `<td class="r5 c16"></td>`) to ease navigation between them. Your code could look a lot cleaner and the jQuery selectors will be more efficient.